# Real-time or Near real-time analytics application design considerations

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, analytics, near-real-time, bigdata

I am working on the design & implementation of a (near) real-time web-analytics engine. This is similar to [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and [ChartBeat](http://chartbeat.com/). Nearly 150M requests/day are expected. We have an availability of 5 to 8 machines with 2.5GHz (8 core) CPU and 16 GB of RAM each.

I am looking at horizontally scalable solutions for this requirement. Currently, I am analyzing mongo-hadoop combination for this purpose. From what I have understood till now is that it would be difficult to keep all the data at one place (one machine) for analysis. So, Hadoop as data processor and MongoDB as data storage is appearing a good combination to me.

Is there a standard or (I should say) a proven architecture for this kind of an application? What are the design considerations I should take? Is mongo-hadoop combination working for somebody?

Comment: Hadoop and real time? No, haven't heard.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have already read this?

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hadoop+Quick+Start

More details and working examples for sharded configuration here - http://www.slideshare.net/spf13/mongodb-and-hadoop

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation. But this does not mention whether the adapter works fine for sharded configuration as well. I am looking  for more details than a short example.

Comment: Yes it does work with sharded configuration.  Good demo examples here - http://www.slideshare.net/spf13/mongodb-and-hadoop